# Replace space in SEDE query parameter

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to fetch the comments matching with my required keyword, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/431872/comments-having-required-keywords) returns the expected result.

```
SELECT TOP 10 Id [Comment Link]
FROM Comments
WHERE Text LIKE '%##SearchKeyword##%'
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

When the search keyword having the space in it, I want to replace the space with the `%` sign. For an example: the keyword is **Please ASAP** I'm expecting the WHERE clause as `Text LIKE '%Please%ASAP%'` and not [`Text LIKE '%Please ASAP%'`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/431872/comments-having-required-keywords?SearchKeyword=Please+ASAP)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL does have a [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) command. Just do a replace of spaces with percent signs and append another percent sign to the beginning and end.

[Basic example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/431910/comments-having-required-keywords?SearchKeyword=Please+ASAP):

```sql
WHERE Text LIKE '%' + REPLACE('##SearchKeyword##', ' ', '%') + '%'
```

Though putting a wildcard in the middle like that is going to make your queries take forever to run.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not aware we can use SQL commands along with the SEDE query parameters.